# Maple matrix displays as raw text

Tags: matrix, maple

I have a real serious problem with maple, I can't get it to display matrixes probably.
When i input a matrix like `<<4,2>|<2,4>>` it outputs:

```
Matrix(2, 2, {(1, 1) = 4, (1, 2) = 2, (2, 1) = 2, (2, 2) = 4}, 
datatype = anything, storage = rectangular, order = Fortran_order, shape = [])
```

And I have absolutely no idea how to get it to display as a proper matrix, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set prettyprint to 0 in some configuration file or prior to constructing the Matrix?  Observe the following:

```
> interface(prettyprint=0);
1
> <<4,2>|<2,4>>;
Matrix(2,2,{(1, 1) = 4, (1, 2) = 2, (2, 1) = 2, (2, 2) = 4},datatype =
anything,storage = rectangular,order = Fortran_order,shape = [])
> interface(prettyprint=1);
                                       0

> <<4,2>|<2,4>>;
                                   [4    2]
                                   [      ]
                                   [2    4]
```

Another way to print the Matrix(...) representation is by lprint.  You don't need use lprint unless you would like to examine the representation of a Matrix internallay:

```
> lprint(<<4,2>|<2,4>>);
Matrix(2,2,{(1, 1) = 4, (1, 2) = 2, (2, 1) = 2, (2, 2) = 4},datatype =
anything,storage = rectangular,order = Fortran_order,shape = [])
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit (November 24, 2011):**
My example was based on the command line Maple.  If you're using the GUI version of Maple, you are better off set the default value of prettyprint to 3.  Please see "interface" help page for the explanation.